# What is Microsoft Digital Media Server Module?

Tags: windows-7

I got a message saying that Microsoft Digital Media Server Module has been installed.  I looked it up, and all I can find is what the latest version number is.  So, what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a virtual device used for streaming digital media out to devices on the network. It gets installed and setup when you [enable media streaming via Windows Media Player 12](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Stream-your-media-to-devices-and-computers-using-Windows-Media-Player).

If you want to get rid of it, disable media streaming and then in Device Manager -> Digital Media Devices, Uninstall Microsoft Digital Media Server Module.